# Unmarshal with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I need to unmarshal a XML string into a class that already exists in my project, but I can't figure out how to unmarshal a certain part of the XML to a list of objects. Let me explain with some code:

I have this XML:

```
<user>
  <id>123</id>
  <name>John Doe</name>
  <vaddresses>
    <address>
      <street>Street XYZ</street>
    </address>
    <address>
      <street>Street ABC</street>
    </address>
  </vaddresses>
</user>
```

And I have these classes:

- User

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "User", propOrder = {"id", "name", "addresses"})
public class User {

    @XmlElement
    private int id;

    @XmlElement
    private String name;

    @XmlElement
    private List<Address> addresses;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Address> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(List<Address> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }
```

- Address

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Address", propOrder = {"street"})
public class Address {

    @XmlElement
    private String street;

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }
}
```

When I try to unmarshal the XML into these classes, fields **id** and **name** are processed correctly, but the same doesn't occur with the **addresses**:

- Output

```java
User: 
    Id: 123
    Nome: John Doe
    Addresses: null
```

How do I solve this problem? Is there some JAXB annotation that I can use? And how? Or do I need to create some type of XmlAdapter? (I've tried this one but without success...)

Comment: Shouldn't `addresses` be `vadresses` in your Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage `@XmlElementWrapper` to add a grouping element around your collection:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="vaddresses")
@XmlElement(name="address")
private List<Address> addresses;
```

**Note**

You are adding more annotations than are necessary.  JAXB is configuration by exception so you only need to annotate where you want the XML representation to differ from the default.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change the type of the private property addresses:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "User", propOrder = {"id", "name", "vaddresses"})
public class User {

    @XmlElement
    private int id;

    @XmlElement
    private String name;

    @XmlElement
    private VAddress vaddresses;

    //...
 }

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "VAddress", propOrder = {"addresses"})
public class VAddress {

    @XmlElement
    private List<Address> addresses;

    //...
 }
```

Maybe you can also try the annotation @XmlElementWrapper.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

User.java

```
package generated;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "id",
    "name",
    "vaddresses"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class User {

    protected int id;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String name;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected User.Vaddresses vaddresses;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int value) {
        this.id = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }


    public User.Vaddresses getVaddresses() {
        return vaddresses;
    }

    public void setVaddresses(User.Vaddresses value) {
        this.vaddresses = value;
    }


    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "address"
    })
    public static class Vaddresses {

        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected List<User.Vaddresses.Address> address;

        public List<User.Vaddresses.Address> getAddress() {
            if (address == null) {
                address = new ArrayList<User.Vaddresses.Address>();
            }
            return this.address;
        }


        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
            "street"
        })
        public static class Address {

            @XmlElement(required = true)
            protected String street;


            public String getStreet() {
                return street;
            }

            public void setStreet(String value) {
                this.street = value;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

JaxBExample.java

```
package generated;
import generated.User.Vaddresses.Address;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class JAXBExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

     try {

        File file = new File("D:\\StackOverFlow\\JAXBTest\\file.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        User user = (User) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        System.out.println("ID::"+user.getId());
        System.out.println("Name::"+user.getName());
        System.out.print("Addresses::");
        for(Address address:user.getVaddresses().getAddress())
        {
            System.out.println(address.getStreet());
        }


      } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }
}
```

output:--

ID::123
Name::John Doe
Addresses::Street XYZ
Street ABC

Comment: I've generated JAXB annotated classes from WSDL/XSD before and they followed that type of structure (inner classes), but changing my class structure at this moment isn't an option.